# Configurable Producte—Labels

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, frontend

I have a Shop with a whole bunch of configurable products. There are some attributes for Size and color, whereby technically everything is working fine.

**But** there is one thing I cannot get my head around: How to make Magento print the right label of the Attribute in the right language?

Instead of the Label, which can be set in the »manage Label / Options« tab (inside the attributes' manage view), it prints the attribute code…

How can I make Magento print the Label?

Please see the image below:
The values within the »Manage Titles (Size, Color, etc.)« are just not used in the frontend.

[image]

Thanks in Ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hallo the label you need is managed in the catalog->manage products

[image]

if you check the "Use default"  the label of the attribute is used, otherwise the "Attribute Name" will be used.

I suggest you to use the "Use default" flag so that you can eventually change all the label by the

```
Catalog -> attributes -> attribute.
```